# Issue with FBX ColorIndex values

Tags: export

I saved some FBX files (version 6.1, in ASCII format) in Blender, carrying Vertex Paint information.
I imported the FBX file into Cienam4D and it opened fine, ignoring all the Vertex Paint information, of course.
The number of vertices, correctly reported by Cinema4D is 984.
Opening the FBX in a text editor, I confirmed that the number of vertices is 984. I copied and pasted the vertices coordinates into a new document and searched for a comma. It reported that there were 2951. Since the last coordinate triple doesn't include a comma, this means that there are 2952 coordinates in the list. Since each 3D point is made of three coordinates, the total number of vertices should be 2952/3 and that equals to 984. So, it confirms the number of vertices reported by Cinema4D.
Then I did the same for the ColorIndex list and it reported that it found 3775 commas. So, 3776 index values.
3776?!?!? Shouldn't it be the same as the number of vertices? I mean, shouldn't it have 984 index values?
With this question in mind, I checked the number of polygons. Cinema4D reports 944 polygons.
Dividing 3776 by 944 returns 4. Well, so I assumed that the ColorIndex list should be reporting something like:

#1 - color index of the first point of polygon #1

#2 - color index of the second point of polygon #1

#3 - color index of the third point of polygon #1

#4 - color index of the forth point of polygon #1

#5 - color index of the first point of polygon #2

#6 - color index of the second point of polygon #2

#7 - color index of the third point of polygon #2

#8 - color index of the forth point of polygon #2

#9 - color index of the first point of polygon #3

#10 - color index of the second point of polygon #3

...

Am I correct in assuming this?
I also noticed that the PolygonVertexIndex list contains 1888 values (I counted the minus characters).
1888 / 2 = 944
This means that all faces are defined twice? Why?

Comment: Think this may be out of scope for this SE site, asking details about a non-blender format, if this is a bug it could be reported.

Answer (score 0):

Blender writes a color for the corner of each face, using `MappingInformationType: "ByPolygonVertex"` referencing `ReferenceInformationType: "IndexToDirect"`

The confusion here is likely that different applications may write different kinds of array mappings, neither is wrong, but it can be confusing.

Comment: So, my interpretation of:

#1 - color index of the first point of polygon #1

#2 - color index of the second point of polygon #1

#3 - color index of the third point of polygon #1

#4 - color index of the forth point of polygon #1

#5 - color index of the first point of polygon #2

#6 - color index of the second point of polygon #2

#7 - color index of the third point of polygon #2

#8 - color index of the forth point of polygon #2

#9 - color index of the first point of polygon #3

#10 - color index of the second point of polygon #3
...

is correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, colors are written per face-corner, like UV's.

Comment: Just like UVs? Ok, will try to code a parser in c++ taking that into account. Thank you.